# create table as select working even with enforce-gtid-consistency

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, google-cloud-sql

I have a sql script that contains the statement `create tbl2 as select * from tbl;`

This statement works on a docker mysql with version 5.7 (currently 5.7.19), even though enforce-gtid-consistency is turned on. Relevant lines from the docker compose yml are:

```
image: mysql:5.7
command: --gtid-mode=ON --enforce-gtid-consistency=true
```

This is even though the documentation clearly specifies:

> Since only transactionally safe statements can be logged when --enforce-gtid-consistency is enabled, it follows that the operations listed here cannot be used with this option:
>
> CREATE TABLE ... SELECT statements

The same statement fails with `ERROR 1786 (HY000): Statement violates GTID consistency: CREATE TABLE ... SELECT.` on a google cloud mysql instance.

`show variables like '%gtid%'` returns the same result on the docker mysql and the google cloud instance (and enforce_gtid_consistency is on in both).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primary reason for failure you see is log-bin is NULL in container database though gtid_mode is on and enforce_gtid_consistency is on.  So you must run container with log-bin set   ,  setting this additionally also require to set server-id.  Below is one example to run container where you should be able to reproduce error - " 
ERROR 1786 (HY000): Statement violates GTID consistency: CREATE TABLE ... SELECT.
"

docker run -d --name=my-mysql --env="MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpassword123" --publish 3306:3306  --volume=/u01/mysql:/var/lib/mysql  mysql/mysql-server:5.7.20  --gtid_mode=ON --enforce_gtid_consistency=ON --log-bin=mysql-bin --master-info-repository=table --relay-log-info-repository=table --server-id=1

cheers
raj